# Unable to upload file using PHP

Tags: php, html, css, apache, centos

I am unable to upload files to my CentOS 7 server running httpd using php.

I have searched all over and still cannot figure out why I am unable to upload files. :(

Here is the form:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
            <h2 class="section-heading text-white text-center">Private Upload Page</h2>
            <hr class="light">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="form-group">
              <span class="text-white">Select directory to upload to:</span><br>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="dir" value="/var/www/html/Private/uploads" style="width: 100%;"><br>
              <span class="text-white">Select file to upload:</span><br>
              <input class="form-control" type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" style="width: 100%;"><br>
              <input class="form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit" >
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the php file:

```
<?php
// Check directory from form, otherwise use uploads folder in 
// /var/www/html/Private
if(isset($_POST["dir"])) {
    $target_dir = $_POST["dir"];
    echo "<p>Using " . $target_dir . " for directory.</p><br>";
}
else {
    $target_dir = "/var/www/html/Private/uploads/";
    echo "<p>Using /var/www/html/Private/uploads for directory.</p><br>";
}

$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

I have tried setting using:

```
chmod 777 /var/www/html
```

and:

```
chmod 777 /var/www
```

as well as turned on file write in the php.ini file

as well as turning off the firewall and am still unable to upload a file.

I am newish to web design, so I'm sure it is an issue that I caused. Every page I looked at pointed to permissions but even allowing 777 still did not fix my issue.

Comment: does it work with the default directory?

Comment: and does move_uploaded_file automatically create directories that do not exist?

Comment: I have tried using just $target_dir = "uploads/" but that did not work, what do I put for the default directory? and move_uploaded_file does not create directories that do not exist.

Comment: leave it empty so it picks up the default directory in the `else` - also, you should prepend the root directory (i.e. the directory where the entered dir name will be created) to any dir name entered.

Comment: and make sure there is a trailing slash with either client side or server side validation

Comment: If I leave it empty it sets $target_dir to "" and goes nowhere, but I commented out if (isset($_POST[...]) so that it is only using the default statement that works. I needed a / after the path, and due to my stupidity was not doing so. If you post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: so adding a slash was all that was needed? as for the empty dir, you should probably use `!empty($_POST["dir"])` instead since it will be set but with an empty string.

Comment: so instead of isset() use !empty()?

Comment: yes, the form field value will always be passed even if it's an empty string so it will always be set, and please don't think of it as stupidity, silly mistakes are part of coding :D

Comment: thank you, its just I should know better. I use Linux enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prepend the root directory (i.e. the directory under which the specified directory exists / will be created) to the directory name entered.

Also make sure there is a trailing slash using either client side or server side validation since users may forget to enter it.

Comment: I will add most likely server side validation, but for the most part this is an internal testing webserver for my main domain (this one pulls a mirror down through rsync). So the validation will be mostly for learning purposes. Please upvote my post if it met the criteria for a good post, so that I can build rep.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. Did you enable `file_uploads = On` on your `php.ini`? if not search for `file_uploads directive`and set it to On.

Comment: You don't need to upload the file directly to `/var/www/html/Private/uploads/`  create a temp folder on your current path and upload to it, then move uploaded file to a destination on your local or cloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form class="" id="add_downloadble" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="upload" >
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">File:</label>
                        <div class="form-group">


            <input name="uploaded_file"  class="form-control" id="fileInput" type="file" required>

                            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $session_id ?>"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="name" Placeholder="File Name"  class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="desc" Placeholder="Description"  class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                  <script>
                  jQuery(document).ready(function($){                        
                      e.preventDefault();
                      var _this = $(e.target);
                      var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
                      $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "save.php",
                        data: formData,
                        success: function(html){                              
                          window.location = 'tambah_materi.php';
                        },
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false
                      });
                    });
                  });
                  </script> 


              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">

            <div class="alert alert-info">Centang kelas yang ingin di tambahkan file ini.</div>

                        <div class="pull-left">
                    Check All <input type="checkbox"  name="selectAll" id="checkAll" />
                      <script>
                      $("#checkAll").click(function () {
                        $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
                      });
                      </script>         
                    </div>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table" id="">

                          <thead>
                                  <tr>
                              <th></th>
                              <th>Nama Kelas</th>
                              <th>Subject Code</th>
                              </tr>

                          </thead>
                          <tbody>

                                      <?php $query = mysql_query("select * from teacher_class
                          LEFT JOIN class ON class.class_id = teacher_class.class_id
                          LEFT JOIN subject ON subject.subject_id = teacher_class.subject_id
                          where teacher_id = '$session_id' and school_year = '$school_year' ")or die(mysql_error());
                          $count = mysql_num_rows($query);


                          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                          $id = $row['teacher_class_id'];

                          ?>                             
                          <tr id="del<?php echo $id; ?>">
                            <td width="30">
                              <input id="" class="" name="selector[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                            </td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['class_name']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['subject_code']; ?></td>                                                                   
                          </tr>

                  <?php } ?>



                </tbody>
              </table>


                            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
            <hr>
              <center>
              <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                      <button name="Upload" type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-success" /><i class="icon-upload-alt"></i>&nbsp;Upload</button>
                    </div>
              </div>
              </center>

               </form>
```

save.php file

```
        include('../session.php');
        //Include database connection details
        include("../dbConnector.php"); 
        $connector = new DbConnector();

        $errmsg_arr = array();
        //Validation error flag
        $errflag = false;

        $uploaded_by_query = mysql_query("select * from teacher where teacher_id = '$session_id'")or die(mysql_error());
        $uploaded_by_query_row = mysql_fetch_array($uploaded_by_query);
        $uploaded_by = $uploaded_by_query_row['firstname']."".$uploaded_by_query_row['lastname'];

        /* $id_class=$_POST['id_class']; */
        $name=$_POST['name'];





        //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
        function clean($str) {
            $str = @trim($str);
            if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                $str = stripslashes($str);
            }
            return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
        }

        //Sanitize the POST values
        $filedesc = clean($_POST['desc']);
        //$subject= clean($_POST['upname']);

        if ($filedesc == '') {
            $errmsg_arr[] = ' file diskripsi belum di isi';
            $errflag = true;
        }

        if ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'] >= 1048576 * 5) {
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'file selected exceeds 5MB size limit';
            $errflag = true;
        }


        //If there are input validations, redirect back to the registration form
        if ($errflag) {
            $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
            session_write_close();
            ?>

           <script>
           window.location = 'downloadable.php<?php echo '?id='.$get_id;  ?>';
           </script>
           <?php exit();
        }
        //upload random name/number
        $rd2 = mt_rand(1000, 9999) . "_File";

        //Check that we have a file
        if ((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_file"])) && ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0)) {
            //Check if the file is JPEG image and it's size is less than 350Kb
            $filename = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

            $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);

            if (($ext != "exe") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] != "application/x-msdownload")) {
                //Determine the path to which we want to save this file      
                //$newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/upload/'.$filename;
                $newname = "../admin/uploads/" . $rd2 . "_" . $filename;
                $name_notification  = 'Add Downloadable Materials file name'." ".'<b>'.$name.'</b>';
                //Check if the file with the same name is already exists on the server
                if (!file_exists($newname)) {
                    //Attempt to move the uploaded file to it's new place
                    if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $newname))) {
                        //successful upload
                        // echo "It's done! The file has been saved as: ".$newname;        

                                    $id=$_POST['selector'];
                                                    $N = count($id);
                                                    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
                                                    {           

                       /*  $qry2 = "INSERT INTO files (fdesc,floc,fdatein,teacher_id,class_id,fname,uploaded_by) VALUES ('$filedesc','$newname',NOW(),'$session_id','$id[$i]','$name','$uploaded_by')"; */
                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO files (fdesc,floc,fdatein,teacher_id,class_id,fname,uploaded_by) VALUES ('$filedesc','$newname',NOW(),'$session_id','$id[$i]','$name','$uploaded_by')");
                        mysql_query("insert into notification (teacher_class_id,notification,date_of_notification,link) value('$id[$i]','$name_notification',NOW(),'downloadable_student.php')")or die(mysql_error());

                      }

        }
        }
        }
        }

        /* mysql_close(); */
        ?>
```